# Install Postgresql 9.4 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: postgresql

Im trying to install postgresql 9.4 (because of BDR support) on Ubuntu 18.04, and following [this building tutorial](https://medium.com/@yenthanh/multi-master-replication-for-postgresql-databases-with-postgres-bdr-eb6d8b1bc189).

but when im install some dependencies for postgres, its error

```
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# sudo apt-get build-dep postgresql-9.4
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 builddeps:postgresql-9.4 : Depends: openjade but it is not installable
                            Depends: docbook-dsssl but it is not installable
                            Depends: docbook-xml but it is not installable
                            Depends: docbook-xsl but it is not installable
                            Depends: docbook but it is not installable
                            Depends: opensp but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

its is possible to install postgresql 9.4 on ubuntu 18.04? thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Step 1: Add PostgreSQL Apt Repository**

```
$ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ `lsb_release -cs`-pgdg main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'
$ wget -q https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc -O - | sudo apt-key add -
```

**Step 2: Install PostgreSQL**

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade

$ sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib libpq-dev pgadmin3
```

**Step 3: Connecting to PostgreSQL**

```
$ sudo su - postgres
$ psql
```

To list the databases  type following command

```
postgres-# \l
```

**credit digital ocean**

Comment: this is not the answer, ubuntu 18.04 have default postgresql version 10, i need to install spesific version of postgres (9.4) because only 9.4 support bdr for multi master clustering.

Comment: just try its install 9.6 and 9.4

Comment: thanks, i have try this yesterday buts still error, im trying now with 

```sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.4```

and i can install it. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when trying to install PostgreSQL 9.4 or higher in Centos 7.

But I have found that in the PostgreSQL site they have binaries for several distros and different versions.

For Ubuntu, PostgreSQL maintains its repositories and the instructions to enable and install them can be found in: https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/

In my case it was compile it or install it from there.

Comment: im able to build the postgresql, but not the build depedency, in the postgresql site, there only postgresql.

Comment: when im running postgresql 9.4 in ubuntu 18.04 (im using build deb from postgresql 10.0), this happen

```$ pg_ctl -l ~/log -D ~/9.4-bdr start
server starting
$ cat log
FATAL:  could not access file "btree_gist": No such file or directory
FATAL:  could not access file "btree_gist": No such file or directory
FATAL:  could not access file "btree_gist": No such file or directory
FATAL:  could not access file "btree_gist": No such file or directory
```